# Using mongodb, how can I return a unique list with one field in common?

Tags: mongodb, unique, distinct, aggregation-framework

I 'm trying to return a list of unique titles by the same user/author.  I used

```js
posts.find(
    {'student':user , 'class_number':0}
).sort('created', -1).limit(num).toArray(function(err, items) {
```

which works well as long as there is a `'class_number':0` which there may not always be.  So I tried using `distinct` but I'm not sure how I can provide a query for unique titles.  Is there a better way to do this? Here's some data:

```js
posts.distinct(
    {'student':user , 'title':?}
)
.sort('created', -1).limit(num).toArray(function(err, items) {
```

Data:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53aa0093e99034914b000003"),
    "ans" : 1,
    "author" : "niko",
    "class_number" : 1,
    "comments" : [ ],
    "copy" : false,
    "created" : 1403650195222,
    "current" : "",
    "memorized" : 1,
    "permalink" : "newtest_106677414836872",
    "rem" : 257,
    "student" : "niko",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "title" : "newtest"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53aa0093e99034914b000004"),
    "ans" : 1,
    "author" : "niko",
    "class_number" : 2,
    "comments" : [ ],
    "copy" : false,
    "created" : 1403650195253,
    "current" : "",
    "memorized" : 1,
    "permalink" : "newtest_91237262691445",
    "rem" : 603,
    "student" : "niko",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "title" : "newtest"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53aa0093e99034914b000002"),
    "ans" : 2,
    "author" : "niko",
    "class_number" : 0,
    "comments" : [ ],
    "copy" : false,
    "created" : 1403650195217,
    "current" : "",
    "memorized" : 1,
    "permalink" : "newtest_5614600780868",
    "rem" : 391,
    "student" : "niko",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "title" : "newtest"
}
{
    "title" : "rockin",
    "author" : "niko",
    "student" : "niko",
    "current" : "",
    "permalink" : "rockin_44917561926464",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "comments" : [ ],
    "created" : 1403673810202,
    "memorized" : 1,
    "ans" : 1,
    "rem" : 1,
    "copy" : false,
    "class_number" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("53aa5cd2ff9163968f000002")
}
{
    "title" : "rockin",
    "author" : "niko",
    "student" : "niko",
    "current" : "",
    "permalink" : "rockin_68780016699996",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "comments" : [ ],
    "created" : 1403673810204,
    "memorized" : 1,
    "ans" : 1,
    "rem" : 1,
    "copy" : false,
    "class_number" : 1,
    "_id" : ObjectId("53aa5cd2ff9163968f000003")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for matching the "student" to the "author" then your best bet for hitting this all in one go is the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "user": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$student", "$author" ] },
                    "$student",
                    false
                 ]
            },
            "title": "$title"
        }
    }},
    { "$match": { "_id.user": { "$ne": false } }}
])
```

So the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) brings all the "distinct" combinations of "user" and "title" together while conditionally evaluating under the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator whether those fields are matching or not.

The [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) just filters out those distinct "titles" where the user match evaluated to `false`.